# Winforms Update and BindingSource Update

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

Some questions regarding Winforms Update.

1) If I Update a form, does it also update all its children controls? Microsoft doesn't state anything about children controls.

2) How does a control become invalidated? Say I have a Label that changes in text. Does that mean if I call Form.Update, would the label be picked it up as invalidated, hence it would be Updated (I'd assume if Q1 is true, then this would hold)? Or would I need to call Invalidate on the label control for the update to pick up?

3) I have a DatagridView which is attached to a BindingSource. I noticed that even when I don't explicity call Update on the form, the DatagridView still updates the DatagridView (when I append a new row). I am wondering if it's the case that Winforms BindingSources updates the grid in the background?

Comment: Control.Update() is a direct call to [UpdateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow) (see the notes). Nothing to do with your data or a BindingSource operations. Setting a Label's Text is an indirect call to [SetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw). Control.Invalidate(true) enqueues a paint request, including the Controls' children. Control.Refresh() calls `Invalidate(true)` and `Update()`, meaning refresh this handle and its children and do it now.

Comment: If you have a specific problem related to Controls content updates, post details about the problem you're having, along with the a description of the context where the problem is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to answering your question(s) is to understand WinForm [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/events-overview-windows-forms)

There are several different kinds of events of interest:

- [Form events](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/windows-forms-events-lifecycle/)
- [Control events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/events-in-windows-forms-controls)
- [Data model change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/change-notification-in-windows-forms-data-binding)
- Etc. etc.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Q:  If I Update a form, does it also update all its children controls?

   A: No.  Child controls are updated only as needed - when there's a change that affects that specific control.
2. Q: How does a control become invalidated?

   A: I think you mean "what triggers a control update?"  Then answer is "receiving an event that the control is configured to handle."
3. Q: Why did my DatagridView update automatically?  [Did] Winforms BindingSources updates the grid in the background?

   A: Basically, "Yes".

   Look here for more details:

   - [Change Notification in Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/change-notification-in-windows-forms-data-binding)
   - [How to: Bind data to the Windows Forms DataGridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

SUGGESTION:

Here's a working example you can build and run to better understand what's going on "under the covers":

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240221/DataGridView-Event-Sequences

Comment: So a Form.Update doesn't work the same as a Control.Update? I notice that the Form.Update is immediate, but Control.Form is not. I tested it with changing the text of a label.

Comment: @Drogba Form.Update() is exactly Control.Update(). The Form class derives from Control. The Update() method belongs to the Control class. The timing of a Control's surface painting depends on many factors. As already mentioned in comments, if you have a specific issue, post details about that.